# How do I compare two text files with files paths and output the difference in another text file?

Tags: python

I am working on a code that compares two texts files with each other and outputs them on another text file. So far I keep getting a "uncallable unicode" error in line 5. What is missing in my present code?

```
enter code here
import glob, os, shutil, time, string

def compare(File1,File2):
    with open(File1,'r') as f:
        d=set(f.readlines())


    with open(File2,'r') as f:
         e=set(f.readlines())


    with open('C:\...\results.txt','a') as f:
        for line in list(d-e):
           f.write(line)




compare(r'C:\...\original_contours.txt',r'C:\...\reprojected_contours.txt')
```

Comment: I don't recognize the error *uncallable Unicode*. Please report the exact error including the stack trace.

Comment: Probably he mentioned `'unicode' object is not callable`

Comment: it's probably due to 'special' characters in the file. By default open function guesses encoding based on user preferences. In case you know the exact encoding on these files, mention them in open. Else, you can open files in rb mode (binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module called `difflib` that comes shipped with standard library and it has number of helper classes and functions for various use cases.

Its worth checking out.

[difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `encoding='utf8'` to your code:

```
with open(File1, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    d=set(f.readlines())

...

with open(File2, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
     e=set(f.readlines())
```